# Select query in MySQL works in Workbench, but not in code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get from Database all the users registered on a given date. So, i make the system to send an email. To select the users, i use this:

```
String query="Select mail from users where registered > "+"'"+datestring+"'"+";"
```

Where registered is the column that traks when the user registered, and datestring is a String, where the actual day is stored. So, I finally got a sentence like this one:

```
Select mail from users where registered > '2013-01-28';
```

The matter is... if I copy+paste the sentence in MySQL Workbench, it works like a charm. But, in code, it doesn't works, and the sentence is never launched. Any help?

In case it may helps, im using Grails (executeQuery(query) Method)

Comment: debug datestring in code

Comment: I've got a `println("Datestring: "+datestring)` and it shows the spected result, 2013-01-28. It is retrieved  using `String datestring=date.format('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: No error at all. It simply does not go further. I have put a println "query launched" after the executeQuery() method, and that println is never called. So obviously there is a mistake in the query. But it works if copy+paste the sentence in MySQL Workbench!

Comment: You are saying this `Select mail from users where registered > '2013-01-28';` works in the code?, but with datestring parameter it doesn't in the code?

Comment: Works in MySQL Workbench, bonCodigo

Comment: Just tested `Select mail from users where registered > '2013-01-28';` in code, and it doesn't works. It makes me think in a SQL syntax issue. But why it works if I paste it on Workbench??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your `datestring` to a `date` like:

```
String query="Select mail from users where 
    registered > CAST('"+datestring+"' as DATE);"
```

or as `datetime`:

```
String query="Select mail from users where 
    registered > CAST('"+datestring+"' as DATETIME);"
```

If those doesn't work, try `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
String query="Select mail from users where 
    registered > STR_TO_DATE('"+datestring+"', '%Y-%m-%d');"
```

This assumes that your table column for `registered` is of type `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used findByRegistered method, provided by Grails, instead of launching the SQL query directly, that way I was able to retrieve what I wanted. But i realized that I have to use an object Date in the findBy.... method. So, Andy, i think your answer would have been correct, so I upvote you.